# enableBackgroundDelivery Health-kit iOS15 not working correctly

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, ios15, hkobserverquery

I am working on the health kit. Before iOS15 below code is working correctly I am getting vitals on an hourly basis but in this latest version, I am not getting any vitals event per hour.

I am facing an issue in iOS15 not getting any event in an hourly event. Can anyone help me out? As per apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1614175-enablebackgrounddelivery I have enabled the permission in XCode13 still I am facing this issue.

Here is my code. *(Working code before iOS15)*

```
private func startObservingStepCountChanges() {
    let sampleType =  HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)
    let query: HKObserverQuery = HKObserverQuery(sampleType: sampleType!, predicate: nil, updateHandler: self.stepChangeHandler)
    healthKitStore.execute(query)
    healthKitStore.enableBackgroundDelivery(for: sampleType!, frequency: .hourly, withCompletion: {(succeeded: Bool, error: Error!) in
        if succeeded{
            print("Enabled background delivery of stepcount changes")
        } else {
            if let theError = error{
                print("Failed to enable background delivery of stepcount changes. ")
                print("Error = \(theError)")
            }
        }
    } as (Bool, Error?) -> Void)
}

private func stepChangeHandler(query: HKObserverQuery!, completionHandler: HKObserverQueryCompletionHandler!, error: Error!) {

    // Flag to check the background handler is working or not
    print("Backgound Mode activated")
    fireTestPush()           
    completionHandler()
 }
```

Comment: Some discussion here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690974

Comment: Thank you for sending this. Yes, it. seems apple bug. @JoshuaC.Lerner

Answer (score 0):

Check if background app refresh is enabled for your app. If it is and you're still running into this issue, file a feedback assistant report to Apple with sample code and sysdiagnose.

Comment: Yes, I have tested this way too. It seems apple bug to me. The same code is working in the iOS14

Comment: Could you file a report at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com preferably with a sample test project and sysdiagnose

Comment: Yes i have provided report on above url. Are you facing this issue?

Comment: Any news on this subject @MayankPatel ?

Comment: @CedricSoubrie Yes it is not working for iOS 15.0, 15.1 and after the new version, it is working correctly I confirmed this.

Comment: @MayankPatel same for my app

Comment: It's again not working from iOS 16.0. This is embarrassing from the Apple side.

Comment: Could you file a Feedback with details/sample code/sysdiagnose on what’s not working? feedback.apple.com

Comment: Still not working ?